# How much volume can a single transporter transport in a single transport?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter

It was demonstrated in the movie *'Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home'* that the transporter system aboard a Klingon Bird-of-Prey could be used to transport two adult humpback whales (George and Gracie) plus a massive 18,000 cubic feet of sea water into a transparent aluminum tank, built into the ship's hold to receive them.

Combining both the whales and water results in a massive transport, which leads to the question: Has a larger single transport ever been done? How much can actually be transported in a single pass?

Comment: For reference, in *The Voyage Home* Scotty says that they had to transport "four hundred tons" of whales and water, or "eighteen thousand cubic feet of water". [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie4.html)

Comment: Thanks @Xantec, I just found that too and was coming back to edit it into the question.

Comment: Probably the maximum single transport capacity is limited by the targeting scanners (can they encompass the entire mass) and the memory capacity available in the transporter buffers.

Comment: This maybe of interest. Not exactly a dup. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47246/what-was-the-largest-object-enterprise-d-could-transport-onboard

Comment: @MajorStackings -I saw that when I was forming the question but rejected it as too narrow and specific to answer the question considering the sheer volume transported by that Bird of Prey.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the VOY episode ["Distant Origin"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Distant_Origin_%28episode%29), the [Voth transported Voyager](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Voth#Technology) (which is a little bit bigger than a couple of whales) to the inside of their city ship:

> The Voth city ship was massive and extremely powerful in comparison with Starfleet vessels – the Voth were able to beam the USS Voyager into a chamber inside their vessel which could clearly house many more starships.

Comment: Wow. That's a 344m long x 130m wide x 63m high, 700,000 metric ton Intrepid-class starship.

Comment: I can't imagine any transport surpassing that unless it's the Voth doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Per my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47246/what-was-the-largest-object-enterprise-d-could-transport-onboard), the largest object that a **Federation Transporter** can transport without special engineering assistance is 2.8L x 2.5W x 2.0H or 3.45L x 1.0W x 2.0H, equivalent to a [large cargo container](http://www.chesterfieldskips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/8-yd-Builder1.jpg).

The Bird of Prey contain several transporters and these can be used in "[site to site](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Site-to-site_transport)" mode to transport a very considerable volume if they're all tied in together and used at the same time.

---

As far as the largest transport *seen on screen*, in the episode "[Distant Origin](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/distant-origin)", the U.S.S. Voyager (which as Morgan points out in his comment above is a 344m long x 130m wide x 63m high, 700,000 metric ton Intrepid-class starship) is transported inside a massive Voth city-ship;

> **KIM:** *No response. They're locking onto the ship with an energy beam. It's cutting right through our shields!* **Some sort of
>   transporter.**
>
> **JANEWAY:** *Report.*
>
> **KIM:** **We've been beamed inside the alien vessel.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The maximum transport size will usually be a function of the transporter type ( shuttlecraft, personnel, cargo etc. ) and what the current storyline requires. A non-canon book discusses transporting a star.

Comment: Can you remember which book?#

Comment: "and what the current storyline requires." +1

Answer (score 0):

In the VOY episode Prime Factors (Season 1 Episode 9) the aliens are found to possess a transporter-like technology that should have been able to transport the whole ship up to 40,000 light years. Of course there was a technical incompatibility that prevented it from working (and ruining the whole premise of the show), but it is a canon-use of a transporter with at least the potential to move a very large object.

Comment: That was actually a method of folding space, which is quite a different process than the transporters. [Spatial Trajector](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Spatial_trajector)